# Fragment popped call OnViewCreated after PopBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragmenttransaction

i have 1 Activity with 3 Fragments. (A, B and C). So,

Activity -> FragmentContainerView with fragment A

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/host_fragment"
    android:name="cl.gersard.shoppingtracking.ui.product.list.ListProductsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="ListProductsFragment" />
```

Fragment A has a button to go to Fragment B

Fragment A -> Fragment B (with addToBackStack)

Then, i go to from Fragment B to Fragment C

Fragment B -> Fragment C (without addToBackStack)

i need when i save a item in Fragment C, come back to Fragment A, so i dont use addToBackStack.

The problem is when in Fragment C i use

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

or

```
requireActivity().onBackPressed()
```

the Fragment A appears but the method OnViewCreated in Fragment C is called so execute a validations that i have in that Fragment C.

I need from Fragment C come back to Fragment A without calling OnViewCreated of Fragment C

Code of interest

MainActivity

```
fun changeFragment(fragment: Fragment, addToBackStack: Boolean) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.host_fragment, fragment,fragment::class.java.simpleName)
    if (addToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Fragment A (ListProductsFragment)

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupRecyclerView()
    observeLoading()
    observeProducts()
    viewModel.fetchProducts()
    viewBinding.btnEmptyProducts.setOnClickListener { viewModel.fetchProducts() }
    viewBinding.fabAddPurchase.setOnClickListener { addPurchase() }
}

    private fun addPurchase() {
    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).changeFragment(ScanFragment.newInstance(),true) 
}
```

Fragment B (ScanFragment)

```
    override fun barcodeDetected(barcode: String) {
    if (processingBarcode.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity).changeFragment(PurchaseFragment.newInstance(barcode), false)
    }
}
```

Fragment C (PurchaseFragment)

```
    private fun observePurchaseState() {
    viewModel.purchasesSaveState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { purchaseState ->
        when (purchaseState) {
            is PurchaseSaveState.Error -> TODO()
            is PurchaseSaveState.Loading -> manageProgress(purchaseState.isLoading)
            PurchaseSaveState.Success -> {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), getString(R.string.purchase_saved_successfully), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The full code is here https://github.com/gersard/PurchaseTracking

Comment: `onViewCreated` should only be called when the fragment is ... well, being created. If this is happening, you might a bug of some logic that's opening C again unintentionally. Check your code or post a full, working example that illustrates your issue.

Comment: @dominicoder i edited with a pieces of code and the link to the repo, thanks

Comment: I was bored enough to download your project and run it. I was not able to reproduce the issue as you described.

Comment: @dominicoder to reproduce the issue scan a X barcode, in the Fragment C will appear un Snackbar with a message that said "product not found....", then press back button, scan again the barcode, the snackbar appear again, then press back button and the snackbar will appear twice (in Fragment A, the list of products)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I see your issue. You are conditionally adding things to the backstack which put the fragment manager in a weird state.

**Issue**

You start on Main, add the Scanner to the back stack, but not the Product. So when you press back, you're popping the Scanner off the stack but the Product stays around in the FragmentManager. This is why get a new instance each and  every time you scan and go back. *Why* this is happening is not clear to me - seems like maybe an Android bug? You are replacing fragments so it's odd that extra instances are building up.

**One Solution**

Change your `changeFragment` implementation to conditionally *pop the stack* instead of conditionally adding things to it.

```
fun changeFragment(fragment: Fragment, popStack: Boolean) {
    if (keepStack) supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()

    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.host_fragment, fragment,fragment::class.java.simpleName)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null) // Always add the new fragment so "back" works
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Then invert your current logic that calls `changeFragment`:

```
private fun addPurchase() {
    // Pass false to not pop the main activity
    (requireActivity() as MainActivity)
        .changeFragment(ScanFragment.newInstance(), false)
}
```

And ...

```
override fun barcodeDetected(barcode: String) {
    if (processingBarcode.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        // Pass true to pop the barcode that's currently there
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity)
        .changeFragment(PurchaseFragment.newInstance(barcode), true)
    }
}
```